# show focus on Canvas when click on linkbutton in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In my application one Datagrid and down one Canvas is there.

I have a DataGrid with Data. When i select the data in the Data grid, the focus is displayed in the canvas. In the canvas i have a chart component.so when i select the link data on the datagrid the focus should be in the chart component in the canvas. Can any one pls help me out, how to do in flex.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener to listen for a click on the datagrid and then fire off the setFocus method on the chart to set the focus on the chart.

```
dataGrid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void { chart.setFocus() });
```